# Send a PDF document in C# or vb.net to whatsapp?

Tags: c#, vb.net, whatsapp

Does somebody know how I can send or attach a `.pdf` document to Whatsapp in C# or vb.net?

I tried to look in their api, but I didnt find anything.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Think the media endpoint is what your looking for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp Business API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started

or search by tag "WhatsApp chatbot"

https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp

[Twilio c# send attach](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-csharp-aspnet)

Comment: i know there is twilo.im looking for something that dosnt cost